# bokeh timeseries chart axis dateslider

Tags: python, widget, bokeh

Is it possible to display a datetime axis for a timeseries chart as a dateslider widget in Bokeh? So that the chart history updates with the range selected via the dateslider?

If so, can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of the `RangeTool` in the documentation gallery:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/range_tool.html